# Status Message: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'VMName' not found. (Code:ParentResourceNotFound)

Tags: json, azure, wvd

I deploying a hostpool in Azure WVD spring 2020 update
My requirement is to add the customscript extension to the defualt template.

In default template I see couple of nested templates, in that the domain join & DSC extensions are added.

I am trying to add the CSE in the main template and get this error.

Status Message: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'WVDVM-0' not found. (Code:ParentResourceNotFound)

Template here
https://gist.github.com/ramoj25/2c067ff8812e9cccd74b023ef12dddf2

Comment: show the template

Comment: i am unable to paste the template here, how can I send you ?

Comment: upload to gist.github and attach the link to the question, but you could easily edit the relevant part into the question

Comment: Thanks for guiding, here you go the template. https://gist.github.com/ramoj25/2c067ff8812e9cccd74b023ef12dddf2

Comment: It's a hostpool deployment template downloaded and added customscriptextension."type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions", able to deploy the hostpool with the parameters file but failing at customscriptextension, error you can see the question field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the vmResourceGroup is different to the template deployment resource group - this will always fail. [this](https://gist.github.com/ramoj25/2c067ff8812e9cccd74b023ef12dddf2#file-json-L690) has to be deployed to the same resource group as the vm.

another possibility - they are deployed to different regions